# Getting an Assertion error in my django application(1.8.4)

Tags: python, django-models, django-rest-framework

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Stock


class StockSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:

        model = Stock

        #field = ('ticker','volume')
        field = '__all__'
```

I am getting an exception value on running application : `("Creating a ModelSerializer without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute has been deprecated since 3.3.0, and is now disallowed. Add an explicit fields = '__all__' to the StockSerializer serializer.",)`

Comment: Could you please post the code for your StockSerializer class?

Comment: i am new to stackoverflow so little unaware about the format ...if something annoying happen please manage..

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As the error message says, the required attribute is `fields` with an 's', not `field`.

Comment: One just has to change field to fields in serializers.py or whatever you have named it

Answer (score 7):

I assume that your serializer currently looks like:

```
class StockerSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Stock
```

The issue Django is complaining about is that the meta class needs to define which fields in the Stock model it needs to serialize. You have three options: you can either put `fields = (‘some’, ‘fields’,...)`, `exclude = (‘fields’, ‘other’, ‘than’, ‘these’...)`, or `fields = ‘__all__’`.

The easiest option is the last one and it will cause the serializer to serialize all the fields in the Stock model which is probably what you want. You should then revise your code to look like:

```
class StockerSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Stock
        fields = ‘__all__’
```

Comment: thank Rohan issue is solved as Daniel told me that i am using field instead of fields....and it works for me..

Answer (score 0):

In my case I made a typo mistake.
I wrote `field` instead of `fields`